# How to filter through a subset of rows using multiple conditions in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I would like to select all the clients who purchased any product ranging from (product 1 to product 19) then purchased product 20 and these transactions must have occured after jan 1st 2018.
-Productid column contains 20 products (product 1 to product 20)
I'll need the first group of people in a column and the other in another column which will give me the proportion.

```
SELECT productid
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT(Primaryid))
    ,something
FROM transactions
WHERE Transactiondate >= '2018-01-01'
GROUP BY productid
```

Here's a sample of expected result:

[image]

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result? that really help

Comment: ive just added a sample of what Im looking for @D-Shih

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the list of clients that meet your criteria

Using `IN`

```
select Primaryid
from transactions
WHERE Transactiondate >= '2018-01-01'
and Primaryid in (select distinct Primaryid from transactions where productid < 20 and Transactiondate >= '2018-01-01')
and productid  = 20
```

Using `EXISTS`

```
select t.Primaryid
from transactions t
WHERE t.Transactiondate >= '2018-01-01'
and exists (select t2.Primaryid from transactions t2 where t2.productid < 20 and t2.Transactiondate >= '2018-01-01' and t2.Primaryid = t.Primaryid)
and t.productid  = 20
```

I'm not sure what *proportion* is in your question, but you should be able to get it from here. Here's a stab at it.

```
select 
    t.productid
    ,total = (select count(*) from transactions tt where tt.productid = t.productid)
    ,ThenBoughtProduct = count(t.Primaryid)
from transactions t
WHERE t.Transactiondate >= '2018-01-01'
        and exists (select t2.Primaryid from transactions t2 where t2.productid < 20 and t2.Transactiondate >= '2018-01-01' and t2.Primaryid = t.Primaryid)
        and exists (select t3.Primaryid from transactions t3 where t3.productid = 20 and t3.Transactiondate >= '2018-01-01' and t3.Primaryid = t.Primaryid)
group by 
    t.productid
```

Comment: This wouldnt work because  I need two 3 columns. First shows products. Second will show people who bought those products (1-19) during the year. the third will show people who bought those products first then bought product 20 after. this allows me to see the proportion.

Comment: ive just edited my question with a sample of expected result.

Comment: ok added an edit... run the last query again and see if that works

Comment: gives me no result at all

Answer (score 0):

I would not normally want to look at this product by product, because individual clients could be counted multiple times.

But you seem to want to.  So, the following uses window functions to get the minimum date for each product and the maximum for product 20.  It then uses this information to get the columns you want:

```
select productid,
       count(distinct primaryid) as num_clients,
       count(distinct case when min_product_date < max_product20_date then primaryid) as num_clients_20_later
from (select t.*,
             max(case when t.productid = 20 then t.transactiondate end) over (partition by t.primarykey) as max_product20_date,
             min(t.transactiondate) over (partition by t.primarykey, t.productid) as min_product_date
      from transactions t
      where t.Transactiondate >= '2018-01-01'
     ) t
group by productid;
```

Comment: well i would like to have a column of the people who bought any products !=20 and create a column with that grouping them by products. then from this set of people , which of them bought product 20. and then create another column. this will allow me to find the proportion of people who bought product 20 after having bought any other.

Comment: @Ismafoot . . . I think that's what this does.

Comment: I think i made it work but not sure what the second COUNT statement and the MIN Statement does...